# What is the difference between a worn wheel bearing and a worn wheel assembly?

Tags: wheel-bearing, hub

By wheel bearing I think one is referring to the little circle thing that goes through the center of the wheel hub.  So if it is worn it is referring to that small circular item.

When one says that the wheels bearing assembly is worn or the wheel hub assembly is worn do they mean things like the studs on the hub are worn rather than the wheel bearing i.e. the small circular part? please clarify the terms and what things are being worn.

Answer (score 1):

I would presume they are talking about the same thing.  Really the only things that can wear in the hub are the bearings and oil seals.  It used to be possible to replace the bearings in the hubs on most cars, but regularly now, the whole hub has to be replaced, making the job a lot easier.

It is possible, depending on the design, that there could also be worn splines in the hub assembly, but it is most likely the bearings that wear.